# Generating progressive web app image icons and various size requirements

Tags: create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

I'm using `create react app` and it generates the following manifest.json in public directory :

```
{
  "name": "React_Starter",
  "short_name": "React_Starter",
  "theme_color": "#1d9ed6",
  "background_color": "#1d9ed6",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "Scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/android-chrome-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/android-chrome-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/android-chrome-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/android-chrome-256x256.png",
      "sizes": "256x256",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/android-chrome-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/android-chrome-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "splash_pages": null,
}
```

Are these image sizes good enough for a production Progressive Web App(PWA)? or should I include more sizes?

Additionally, is there a tool I can use with `create react app` without `ejecting` to generate the PWA image icons given a `logo.png` and save to the build directory

Comment: I hope my answer will help

Answer (score 4):

If you want to generate a lot of icons in different sizes you can use this: https://realfavicongenerator.net

Answer (score 2):

I think you've got a decent amount of icon sizes in that list!

According to the Google Developers Website, the baseline icon sizes are [48x48, 196x196, 128x128, 144x144, 152x152](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/).

From the site:

> When saving an icon to the home screen, Chrome first looks for icons
>   that match the density of the display and are sized to 48dp screen
>   density. If none are found, it searches for the icon that most closely
>   matches the device characteristics. If, for whatever reason, you want
>   be specific about targeting an icon at a particular pixel density, you
>   can use the optional density member, which takes a number. When you
>   don’t declare density, it defaults to 1.0. This means: “use this icon
>   for screen densities 1.0 and up”, which is normally what you want.

You could keep on adding more and more icon sizes, but ultimately, Chrome will handle this for you as long as you have a good list of icon sizes.

I find that as long as the manifest file validates, you should be good to go. Have you tried the [Manifest Validator](https://manifest-validator.appspot.com/) that follows the rules from the W3C specification?